# Retornar dados de uma consulta com o Linq em um repositório EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Tenho a classe Pessoa que se relaciona com as tabelas PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica em um relacionamento um para um. Na minha tabela Pessoa tenho o campo PessoaNatureza onde 0 = Pessoa Física e 1 = Pessoa Jurídica.

Uma pessoa pode ser física ou  jurídica e quem define isso é o Campo PessoaNatureza. Existe uma maneira de eu dar um include na tabela PessoaFisica, somente se PessoaNatureza for igual a 0 e dar um include na tabela PessoaJuridica somente de PessoaNatureza for igual 1?

```
public class PessoaRepository : Repository<Pessoa>, IPessoaRepository
{
        public PessoaRepository(SistemaComercialContext context)
            :base(context)
        {

        }

        public IQueryable<Pessoa> GetAllJoin()
        {
            return DbSet //DbSet Pessoa
                .Include("PessoaFisica")
                .Include("PessoaJuridica")
                .AsNoTracking();
        }        
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `Entity Framework Core` existe uma possibilidade em fazer o carregamento das relações ***e/ou*** as coleções posteriormente, ***exemplo***:

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
    var pessoa = db.Pessoa.Find(1);
    if (pessoa.PessoaNatureza == 0)
    {
        db.Entry(pessoa)
            .Reference(x => x.PessoaFisica)
            .Load(); // Carregando só se for Pessoa Fisica
    }
    else
    {
        db.Entry(pessoa)
            .Reference(x => x.PessoaJuridica)
            .Load(); // Carregando só se for Pessoa Juridica
    }
}
```

esse tipo de carregamento é um novo recurso, que inclusive também tem como filtrar os elementos que poderiam ser carregados, mas, não é o caso em especifico.

Na sua camada poderia conduzir esse mesmo código com algumas alterações, ***exemplo***:

```
public class PessoaRepository : Repository<Pessoa>, IPessoaRepository
{
    public PessoaRepository(SistemaComercialContext context)
        :base(context)
    {

    }

    public List<Pessoa> GetAllJoin()
    {
        var pessoas = context.Pessoa.ToList();
        pessoas.ForEach(x =>
        {                    
            if (x.PessoaNatureza == 0)
            {
                context.Entry(x)
                    .Reference(f => f.PessoaFisica)
                    .Load();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(x)
                    .Reference(j => j.PessoaJuridica)
                    .Load();
            }
        });
        return pessoas;     
    }        
}
```

Sobre desempenho, se a quantidade de registro for muito grande pode ter baixo desempenho, então, tem que ponderar isso tudo, talvez um paginação de resultados seria o ideal, mas, quis mostrar o recurso de carregamento das relações após a carga de algum dado.

Comment: Pois é Virgilio, agora fiquei com dúvida... é uma app comercial e conterá muitos registros, pois clientes, fornecedores, transportadoras, etc, serão "Pessoas" e o banco está normalizado... O Ruim de se Normalizar e usar boas práticas, nem sempre é bom, pois perderia performance no meu caso. Não haveria uma maneira de melhorar isso não? Como seria o processo de paginação?

Comment: Então, nas minha visão as suas tabelas não estão totalmente normalizadas, porque 1:1 eu montaria de outra forma (ou até nem montaria), a melhor forma no seu caso é paginação, poderia utilizar um plugin para isso exemplo: https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc.Core/ @JalberRomano

Comment: Não estou conseguindo usar o "context" ex: context.Pessoa.ToList(); Só consigo ter acesso ao DbSet...... Mas quando tento usar DbSet.Entry(x) tb dpa erro no Entry...

Comment: Será que é correto fazer assim?          public IEnumerable<Pessoa> GetAllJoin()
        {
            var pessoas = DbSet.ToList();
            pessoas.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (x.PessoaNatureza == 0)
                {
                    DbSet.Include("PessoaFisica");
                }
                else
                {
                    DbSet.Include("PessoJuridica");
                }
            });
            return pessoas;
        }

Comment: @JalberRomano esse trecho de código não é igual o que eu fiz, então, está errado !!! porque é uma lista e não um item só... OK! e na interação tem que pegar o item e verificar qual tipo de pessoa é

Comment: Eu tentei alterar pois context.Pessoa não funciona no meu repository.... Substitui por DbSet... Só que ainda dá erro no .Entry.... Diz que não existe...

Comment: Tem que pegar o variavel do contexto @JalberRomano tipo `Repository<Pessoa>`o que tem dentro

Comment: Funcionou @Virgilio Novic. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Não existe uma maneira "bonita" pra você fazer isso, já que o `Include` não suporta condições.

Uma forma é você separar em duas queries e depois juntá-la:

```
return DbSet.Where(p => p.PessoaNatureza == 0)
            .Include("PessoaFisica")
            .Concat(
                   DbSet.Where(p => p.PessoaNatureza == 1)
                        .Include("PessoaJuridica")
            ).AsNoTracking();
```

Dessa forma você mantém o trabalho no banco e tem o resultado que espera.

Existem outras formas, utilizando objetos anônimos para retornar os dados e depois filtrar in memory. Um exemplo [neste link](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232741-include-with-filtering-or-limiting/) que também contém um código para uma extensão de `IQueryable` para este "problema" do `Include`.