# Expressão lambda para retornar uma Pessoa no repositório - DDD e Aspnet.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Possuo uma tabela Pessoa que possui relacionamento um para um com as tabelas `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu passo o id, ele tem que me checar se a natureza é física ou jurídica e me trazer a pessoa + `pessoafisica` ou `pessoajuridica` (A pessoa só pode ser um dos dois). Como eu monto uma expressão lambda para isso? Abaixo, tenho uma que estou tentando montar:

```
public Pessoa GetJoinById(int id)
{
            var pessoa = Db.Pessoa.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
                //.Include("")
                //.Include("")
            pessoa.(x =>
            {
                if (x.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
                {
                    Db.Entry(x)
                        .Reference(f => f.PessoaFisica)
                        .Load();
                }
                else
                {
                    Db.Entry(x)
                        .Reference(j => j.PessoaJuridica)
                        .Load();
                }
            });

            return null;
}
```

Comment: Foi eu que postei isso em outra pergunta mas, está diferente, ta errado isso! Qual é a sua duvida?

Comment: Sim Virgilio.. acho que foi vc mesmo... Naquele caso, eu estava tentando mandar uma lista e funcionou 100% Preciso adaptar para ele fazer o mesmo, só que enviando apenas uma pessoa.... Não manjo de de lambda.. só de sql....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mediante [essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276624/54880), pode trazer uma `Pessoa` com a referencia se é `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica` da seguinte forma:

```
public Pessoa GetJoinById(int id)
{
    var pessoa = Db.Pessoa.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if  (pessoa != null)
    {
        if (pessoa.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
        {
            Db
                .Entry(pessoa)
                .Reference(f => f.PessoaFisica)
                .Load();
        }       
        else
        {
            Db
                .Entry(pessoa)
                .Reference(f => f.PessoaJuridica)
                .Load();
        }
        return pessoa;
    }   

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez Virgilio!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você não tem um campo na tabela que indica o documento? Como CPF ou CNPJ?

Tenta fazer o seguinte:

```
var pessoa = Db.Pessoa.Where(x => x.PessoaId == id).FirstOrDefault();
if (pessoa.Natureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica){
    //carrega para pessoa fisica
}
else{
    //carrega para pessoa juridica
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição Gabriel!!!