# C# - Filtrar Include - Contexto

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

No método abaixo, eu retorno alguns registros da minha entidade ConsultaIntramexRegras, onde a mesma possui relação com os .INCLUDE ("Emails e Parametros"). Ciente de que o EF não permite filtrar no .INCLUDE, gostaria de verificar como filtrar essas entidades?

```
return ctx.ConsultaIntramexRegras
                .Include("Emails")
                .Include("Parametros")                    
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Preciso que seja filtrado da seguinte maneira:

```
var regras = ctx.ConsultaIntramexRegras.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            var emails = ctx.ConsultaIntramexRegrasEmails.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id && p.Status);
            var parametros = ctx.ConsultaIntramexRegrasParametros.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id && p.Status == 1);
```

Os Modelos:

```
  public class ConsultaIntramexRegras : EntityBase<int, string>
{        
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int Periodicidade { get; set; }
    public int DiaSemanaMes { get; set; }
    public int Horario { get; set; }        
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int CodigoConsulta { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConsultaIntramexRegrasEmails> Emails{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsultaIntramexRegrasParamentros> Parametros { get; set; }
}

   public class ConsultaIntramexRegrasEmails : EntityBase<int, string>
{
    public string Emails { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int RegrasID { get; set; }

    public virtual ConsultaIntramexRegras Regras { get; set; }
}
  public class ConsultaIntramexRegrasParamentros : EntityBase<int, string>
{        
    public int RegrasId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int ParametroId { get; set; }
    public int SequenciaParametro { get; set; }
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string TrataData { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ConsultaIntramexRegras Regras { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tem como adicionar na pergunta os 3 modelos?

Comment: Claro! Adicionado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework relacionado.

Comment: Se for na versão Core: essa tem essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276603/retornar-dados-de-uma-consulta-com-o-linq-em-um-reposit%C3%B3rio-ef-core/276624#276624

Comment: @VirgilioNovic agradeço os exemplos. Queria evitar usar bibliotecas de terceiros. Como medida paliativa fiz da seguinte forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um modelo aqui que tem a opção "`where`" nos 3 modelos e retorna `ConsultaIntramexRegras`.

```
public ConsultaIntramexRegras obterRegraConsultaIntramexPorId(int id)
{
    ConsultaIntramexRegras regra;
    using (var ctx = new IntramexContext())
    {
        regra = ctx.Set<ConsultaIntramexRegrasParamentros>()
            .Where(p => p.ParametroId == 1)//Where em ConsultaIntramexRegrasParamentros
            .Include(p => p.Regras)
            .Select(p => p.Regras)
            .Where(p => p.Periodicidade == 1)//Where em ConsultaIntramexRegras
            .Include(p => p.Emails)
            .SelectMany(p => p.Emails)
            .Where(p => p.Emails == "")//Where em ConsultaIntramexRegrasEmails
            .Select(p => p.Regras)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return regra;
}
```

Comment: @BrunoSouza Que problema deu? imagina, não precisa se desculpar.

Comment: @BrunoSouza editei minha resposta, veja agra

Comment: @BrunoSouza ajustado novamente, mals mandar errado, chefe chegou na sala

Comment: @BrunoSouza feliz em ajudar. obs: depois deleta as respostas que vc deu, se não o pessoal vai negativar, elas deveriam ser edições da pergunta, abraço

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma. Evitei o uso de bibliotecas de terceiros.
Não foi a melhor maneira, creio que exista outras mais eficaz. Estarei em pesquisa e retorno caso encontre solução mais simples!

```
    public ConsultaIntramexRegras obterRegraConsultaIntramexPorId(int id)
    {

        List<ConsultaIntramexRegras> regra;

        using (var ctx = new IntramexContext())
        {
            regra = ctx.ConsultaIntramexRegras
                .Include(p => p.Emails)
                .Include(p => p.Parametros)
                .Where(p => p.Id == id).ToList();
        }

        return regra.Select(p => new ConsultaIntramexRegras
                    {
                        CodigoConsulta = p.CodigoConsulta,
                        DataRegistro = p.DataRegistro,
                        Descricao = p.Descricao,
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Parametros = p.Parametros.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList(),
                        Emails = p.Emails.Where(s => s.Status == true).ToList(),
                        Status = p.Status,
                        OperadorRegistroId = p.OperadorRegistroId,
                        DiaSemanaMes = p.DiaSemanaMes,
                        Horario = p.Horario,
                        Periodicidade = p.Periodicidade
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: É uma forma de fazer trabalhar com os dados em memória, mas, que acarreta baixo desempenho, porque, além do mais traz aquilo que não precisa ... ! ... Sempre tente trazer da sua base o que precisa, um dos gargalho de desenvolvimento é relação aplicação e repositório de informação. O pacote é excelente é bem utilizado pelo mundo .NET pra EF 6x, já a versão Core já existe como fazer isso.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vc tem razão. Vou usá-lo em próximos projetos.